# Email service is not running

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I have an apex class sending an email to a custom email service, The email service is either not running, or is not working.

Apex snippet that sends the email to the service:

```
    public static void sendEmailToCreatePDF(Id id) {
    EmailServicesAddress esa = [SELECT Id, EmailDomainName, LocalPart FROM EmailServicesAddress WHERE LocalPart = 'createpdf' ];
    String e = esa.LocalPart + '@' + esa.EmailDomainName;
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    email.setPlainTextBody(String.valueOf(id));
    email.setToAddresses(new String[]{e});
    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});
    System.debug(r);
}
```

Email service:

```
global class LiabilityWaiverEmailHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope env) {
    System.debug('from: ' + email.fromAddress);
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    String myPlainText = email.plainTextBody; //should be liability waiver Id
    System.debug(myPlainText);
    LiabilityWaiverController.savePDF(myPlainText);
    result.success = true;
    return result;
}
```

}

Email service settings

[image]

Email service email settings:

[image]

In the debug logs I see the code makes it all the way to successfully sending the email, but then nothing from the email service seems to run, and I do not receive an error email.

```
01:29:04:248 USER_DEBUG [118]|DEBUG|(Messaging.SendEmailResult[getErrors=();isSuccess=true;])
```

Comment: Have you tried sending an email from a typical email client to your handler, just to see if it gets to the email service?

Comment: @DavidCheng looks like if I send from Gmail it works